# Robocopy copy files source to destination date range

Tags: windows, command-line, robocopy

I am trying to copy the folders and files created between the date range. But this following command looks like copying everything from the source ignoring the date range. What could be wrong?

```
robocopy c:\source c:\destination /E /dcopy:t /MAXAGE:20100101 /MINAGE:20110101
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to match creation date, and not access date of the files? Windows by default shows the last access date, not the creation date. If you want to see creation date (from CMD), use "dir /TC". If you want to match acces date, use /MINLAD:xxxx and /MAXLAD:xxxx

Answer (score 0):

The /maxage and /minage switches in robocopy seem to refer to the modified date. It is not obvious from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) but if you try for yourself you can easily verify that. There are no switches for the creation date so I believe the only solution here is powershell if the difference in performance is acceptable to you.